# fastest way to determine if an element is in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of sorted ints with a 1,000 or more values (could be up to 5000+). I need to write a function that receives an int and returns a bool based on the element being in the array. I know I can write  a for loop with a break, I know I can use jquery .InArray.

What would be the best way to implement this, KNOWING that the array is sorted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Knowing that the array is sorted a binary search would be the best approach.

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/01/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search/

Answer (score 10):

I think you'd want to use a binary search routine.  A binary search routine is [image] whereas a linear search is, on average, [image].

There are many variations to choose form.  Here's one I found in [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/01/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search/):

```
function binarySearch(items, value){

    var startIndex  = 0,
        stopIndex   = items.length - 1,
        middle      = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex)/2);

    while(items[middle] != value && startIndex < stopIndex){

        //adjust search area
        if (value < items[middle]){
            stopIndex = middle - 1;
        } else if (value > items[middle]){
            startIndex = middle + 1;
        }

        //recalculate middle
        middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex)/2);
    }

    //make sure it's the right value
    return (items[middle] != value) ? -1 : middle;
}
```

Or this simpler looking version from [this article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search) that has a binary search function in a zillion different languages.

```
function binary_search_iterative(a, value) {
    var lo = 0, hi = a.length - 1, mid;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = Math.floor((lo+hi)/2);
        if (a[mid] > value)
            hi = mid - 1;
        else if (a[mid] < value)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return null;
}
```

There's also a binary search in Google closure with the code [here](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_array_array.js.source.html#line881).

And, a good description of how the binary search algorithm works on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).

Answer (score 3):

If the array's sorted, then the answer's sorted - use a binary chop.

Answer (score -1):

If doing lookups more than once, migrate to a map-like object.

```js
var fastLookup = {};
mySortedArray.forEach(function(i){fastLookup[i]=true)});

//Each time:
  if (fastLookup[key]===true){ //do thing
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Many languages already have this implemented for example in java you can just use CollectionsCollections.binarySearch(List> list, T key) method and I'm pretty sure C# also has some sort of BinarySearch method.