# javascript: fastest way finding is a string is in a set of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, sorting

I need a fast way to find if a string is in a set of strings.

My set does not change much over time, so putting it in a sorted array and using binary search is an option (as advised here: [fastest way to determine if an element is in a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264239/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-element-is-in-a-sorted-array))

But would using a trie be faster considering we are talking about String ? If so, is there a well known and supported implementation I could use ? (found a few one on github, but did not seem supported or broadly used).

I was also reading:
[Fast way to find if a string is in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476056/fast-way-to-find-if-a-string-is-in-an-array)

Any chance this approach could beat using a trie ?

(I do not have the time to try to implement all the approaches and benchmark them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have JavaScript. If you go with trie, it would be your own implementation in JavaScript, while a hash is pretty much the foundation the whole JavaScript is built on, optimised to hell in the execution environment. I'd just do this:

```
var STRINGS = {
  "foo": true,
  "bar": true
}

var fooExists = STRINGS.hasOwnProperty("foo");
```

Comment: maybe this is just the answer I am looking for, just that building a dictionary for such purpose is so counter intuitive ...

Comment: If it helps you with the "counter-intuitive" bit, Ruby's `Set` and Java's `TreeSet` use the exactly same method (having a composed `Hash` and `TreeMap`, respectively) ;)

Comment: yes, that actually helps :) Actually that may even explain why there are no broadly used implementation of trie ?

Comment: I don't know, really. For large databases I imagine native trie will beat a native hash (either in memory or in speed, depending on number of buckets hash is allocated with); but native hash to beat scripted trie. However, without a benchmark it's just speculation.